# Atlassian - Jira software

Tags: jira

I am trying to  create an environment with Jira 7.7 software, from Atlassian.
I wanted to do it inside a Virtual Machine in my local host.
In Atlassian Website they only talk in VMWare, for virtualization.
(https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/supported-platforms-938846830.html).

I am not sure if I can use Hyper-V (in Windows Server 2016).
Do you know If I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jira is a fancy application, and reasonably complex, but in the end it's still Java code running via Tomcat. That's all pretty straightforward, and a typical workload for virtualized environments. It should just work.

Note that your VMWare link talks a lot about optimization. That's an advanced topic, beyond getting things to work. Tuning Hyper-V is a similar task.